# Can my school, download my app from website?

Tags: ios, xcode, download, app-store

In order to be able to download apps from a site (not going from AppStore) is the Dev Enterprise license required or the normal one?
Or can not you do it?
The idea would be to have the whole school download an app for a web-radio institute, without having to trust it every week

Comment: The school would need an enterprise membership. You could then distribute your app via a website.  Users would get prompted to trust the school's app signing the first time that they try to run the app. You would need to update the app each year as the provisioning profile will expire

Comment: There is a fee for the enterprise programme. Your best bet, if you don't want to pay this, is to follow the common route through Testflight but have your users put up with having to accept the trust certificate.